# One-point compactification problem

Tags: general-topology

I am a little bit confused about that question.

$A=[0,1)\cup [2,3).$
Prove that the one-point compactification $A^{+}$ of $A$ is homeomorphic to a closed interval.

I think it is possible to choose $[0,1]$ and show that $f:[0,1]\rightarrow A^{+}$ is homeomorphic, but I am not sure.
Is it a right way to do? And if it is then I have shown that the map is bijective and don't really know how to show that the map $f$ is continuous and that the inverse is continous too. Maybe you have another way to solve the problem.

Thank You

Comment: The "correct" one-point compactification is where you map $[2,3)$ to $[2,1)$ and then make $1$ the "compactification point"

Comment: So the correct function takes $x \in [0,1)$ to $x$, $\infty$ to $1$, and $x \in [2,3)$ to $4-x$, and the codomain is $[0,2]$.

Comment: @KennyLau is right, but it might be good to mention a more pictorial way to see what's going on. The 1-point compactification of $[0,1)$ is obtained by attaching one point at the open end of the interval; likewise for $[2,3)$. But for $[0,1)\cup[2,3)$, you need to add the same point to the open end of both intervals. So you get this one new point with two intervals attached to it, looking like the letter V. But that's homeomorphic to a closed interval by folding down both sides of the V. (If you write this out in formulas, in the easiest way you can find, you'll get Kenny's formula.

Answer (score 2):

Thank You all for your answers. I now write my answer and hope someone would give me some feedback.

A=[0,1)U[2,3). Then I chose f:[0,2]->A+. Want to show that the map is bijectiv and continous.

Bijectiv because:

f:[0,2]->A+

[0,1)->[0,1)
(1,2]-> [2,3)
1-> x_0 
where x_0 is the point at infinity in the one-point compactification A+ of A. 
Is it right?

Continous:
Take U open in [0,2] and want to show that the image is open in A+. 
But from here I am confused?

Answer (score 1):

Theorem:

> If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space and $Y$ is compact Hausdorff such that for some point $p \in Y$, $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y\setminus \{p\}$, then $Y$ is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $X$.

Proof: Let $h: X \to Y\setminus \{p\}$ be the promised homeomorphism.
Define $h': \alpha(X) = X \cup \{\infty\} \to Y$ by $h'(x) = h(x)$ for $x \in X$ and $h'(\infty) = p$. Then $h'$ is clearly a bijection. To see it is continuous, let $O \subseteq Y$ be open. If $p \notin O$, then $O \subseteq Y\setminus \{p\}$ and this set is open in that subspace so that $h'^{-1}[O] = h^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$ and so open in $\alpha(X)$. If $p \in O$ then $Y \setminus O \subseteq Y\setminus \{p\}$ is compact and so is $C:= h^{-1}[Y \setminus O]$ as $h$ is a homeomorphism, and $h'^{-1}[O] = \{\infty\} \cup (X\setminus C)$ is also open in $\alpha(X)$ (by the definition of the topology on the one-point compactification $\alpha(X)$). So $h'$ is a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space hence a homeomorphism.

Then note that $(1,2] \simeq [2,3)$ (via $f:[2,3) \to (1,2]; f(x) = -x + 4$) and so

$$[0,1) \cup [2,3) \simeq [0,1) \cup (1,2] = [0,2] \setminus \{1\}$$

so $[0,2]$ is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of the first space.

Comment: But we dont really know something about A and A+ besides that A is a locally compact subspace of the real line R?

Comment: @Sumi So we can use $X=A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\infty$ be the point at infinity in the one-pint compactification B of A. Define $f:[0,2] \to B$ by $f(2)=\infty$, $f(x)=x$ if $0 \leq x <1$ and $f(x)=x+1$  if  $1 \leq x <2$. This f is a bijection and it it easy to show from the definition of the topology on B that it is continuous. Its inverse is automatically continuous since the domain and range are compact and Hausdorff.

Comment: I am still a little bit confused. So you choose the closed interval to be [0,2]? And is B=A+? And from there I dont really understand how do you show the homeomorphism?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x$ for $0\leq x<1$ and $f(x)=4-x$ for $2\leq x<3.$ Then $f:A\to B=[0,1)\cup (1,2]$  is a homeomorphism, and $id_B:B\to [0,2]$ is a one-point compactification of $B.$