# How to prove a quotient space is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification

Tags: general-topology

I have some trouble proving the following: 
If I know that X is a compact Hausdorff space, A is a closed subspace and X/A denotes the quotient space of X which identifies A to a single point.

I have proved that X/A is again compact and Hausdorff and I am allowed to assume that A is not also open and hence the complement X − A is not compact.

Now I would like to show that X/A is homeomorphic to the one point compactification $(X − A)^+$ of X − A.

But I'm not quite sure how to..

Comment: Try constructing an explicit homeomorphism $f:X/A\to (X\setminus A)^+$. Where should $f$ send $x\not\in A$? Where should $f$ send $x\in A$?

Comment: I'm not sure because topology is still a little weird to me and I'm having some trouble ''seeing'' what's going on.. 
But if f maybe send x∉A to the extra point and all the x in A to X-A? But I don't feel like this is a homeomorphism..

Comment: One intuitive way to view a quotient space $X/A$ is you start with the space $X$, you take the set $A$, then smush it down to a single point. So $x\in X\setminus A$ is unchanged, and $x\in A$ is all identified with some single point. You're just trying to formally prove that intuition. So try to make a homeomorphism $f:X/ A\to (X\setminus A) ^+$ that's the identity on $X\setminus A$, and sends $x\in A$ to $\infty$, the point added in the one-point compactification.

Comment: Arrh, okay I think I can see point. So $ \infinity $ goes to the single point, w, which all the $x \in A$ has gone to. And then the inverse of f just takes w to $\infinity$ and both f and the inverse is just the identity for all the $x \in X - A$ right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2582158/4280) I show a simple result:

> Let $X$ be locally compact Hausdorff (so that its Aleksandrov compacification $\alpha(X)$ (or $X^+$ if one prefers) is well-defined). If $Y$ is a compact Hausdorff space such that for some $p\in Y$, $Y\setminus \{p\}$ is homeomorphic to $X$, then $Y$ is homeomorphic to $X^+$.

This makes the intuition more formal of the idea that $X^+$ is just “something that looks like $X$ with one point added to make a compact result”.

This directly applies to $Y=X / A$, which (one can show) is compact and Hausdorff when $X$ is compact Hausdorff and $A$ is closed. We use as the point $p$ the class of $A$ in the quotient. It’s easy to see that all other classes, so all the singletons outside of $A$, form a subspace of the quotient that is easily seen to be homeomorphic to $X-A$: the restricted quotient map is injective continuous and open. So using the space $X-A$ as $X$ in the theorem (it is locally compact as an open subset of the compact $X$) we see that $X/A\simeq (X-A)^+$.