# Let $(X, T)$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $A \subset X$ be closed. Then $X\backslash A$ is locally compact and Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology

**Attempt Hausdorffness:** I thought I'd start by proving that $Y := X\backslash A$ is Hausdorff because that could be usefull for proving the local compactness.

Suppose $Y$ is not Hausdorff. Then $Y = U \cup V$ for non-empty $U, V$ open in $Y$.  By definition $U, V$ are equal to $U' \cap Y$, $V' \cap Y$ respectively for $U', V'$ open in $X$. As $A$ is closed, $Y$ is open in $X$, so $U, V$ are open in $X$ as well. I thought it might be possible to seperate $A$ in open $C, D$ such that $C \cap D = \emptyset$ and then this would be a contradiction because $U \cap C$ and $V \cap D$ seperate $X$ meaning that $X$ is not Hausdorff. Also $A$ is compact because $X$ is Hausdorff $A$ is closed.

Comment: $Y =  U \cup V$? You're not dealing with connectedness!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma that was a facepalm moment, thanks.

Comment: You probably want [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2586407/4280) next?

Comment: Did you do topology in Utrecht as well or are you psyschic?

Comment: I was just assuming by the questions that I saw recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subspace $S$ of a Hausdorff space $X$ is also Hausdorff. Proof:

Let $x,y \in S$ be distinct; these are points of $X$ so there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ with $x \in U$ and $y \in V$. But then $x \in U \cap S$ is open in $S$ (definition of subspace topology!) and $y \in V \cap S$ is open in $S$ and are still disjoint (as $(U \cap S ) \cap (V \cap S) \subseteq U \cap V = \emptyset$)

So $S$ is Hausdorff in the subspace topology.

Local compactness follows from $X \setminus A$ being open in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

(1).The separation properties $T_0, T_1,T_2, T_3,$ and $T_{3\frac {1}{2}}$ are hereditary. That is if a space $X$ has one of these properties then every sub-space of $X$ also has it.

(2). A compact $T_2$ space is a $T_4$ space, and is, a fortiori, a $T_3$ space. It is also not difficult to prove directly that a compact $T_2$ space is $T_3.$

(3). Let $X$ be a locally compact $T_2$ space. Let the closure bar denote closure in $X.$ Let $A=\bar A\subset X.$

Let $p\in X$ \ $A.$ Let $p\in U$ where $U$ is open in the space $X$ \ $A.$ Then $U$ is also open in $X.$ Let $p\in V \subset  U$ such that  $V$ is open in $X$ and $\bar V$ is compact.  Then $V$ \ $A=V$ \ $\bar A$ is open in $X$ and is  a subset  of   $\bar U,$ so $V$ \ $A$ is an open subset of the  space  $\bar U.$

By (2) there exists  $W\subset V$ \ $A$ such that  $p\in W\subset Cl_{\bar V}(W)\subset V$ \ $A,$ where $W$ is open in the space $\bar U.$   But since $V$ \ $A$ is open in $X,$ it must be that $W$ is open in $X,$ so $W$ is open in the space $U \setminus A.$

And $\bar W=Cl_{\bar U}(W)$ is a closed subset of  the compact $T_2$ space $\bar U,$ so $\bar W$ is compact.

That is, in the space $X$ \ $A,$ the set $W$ is a nbhd of p whose closure in $X$ \ $A$ is compact, with  $W\subset U.$ So $X$ \ $A$ is locally compact.

It may help to draw a Venn-style diagram.